# Join Performances When Searching For NULL Value

Tags: mysql

I need to find a value that exists in `LoyaltyTransactionBasketItemStores` table but not in `DimProductConsolidate` table. I need the item code and its corresponding company. This is my query

```
SELECT
    A.ProductReference, A.CompanyCode
FROM
    (SELECT ProductReference, CompanyCode FROM dwhdb.LoyaltyTransactionsBasketItemsStores GROUP BY ProductReference) A 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT LoyaltyVariantArticleCode FROM dwhdb.DimProductConsolidate) B ON B.LoyaltyVariantArticleCode = A.ProductReference
WHERE
    B.LoyaltyVariantArticleCode IS NULL
```

It is a pretty straight forward query. But when I run it, it's taking 1 hour and still not finish. Then I use EXPLAIN and this is the result

[image]

But when I remove the `CompanyCode` from my query, its performance is increasing a lot. This is the EXPLAIN result

[image]

I want to know why is this happening and is there any way to get `ProductReference` and its company with a lot more better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current query is rife with syntax and structural errors.  I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT a.ProductReference, a.CompanyCode
FROM dwhdb.LoyaltyTransactionsBasketItemsStores a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dwhdb.DimProductConsolidate b
                  WHERE b.LoyaltyVariantArticleCode = a.ProductReference);
```

Your current query is doing a `GROUP BY` in the first subquery, but you never select aggregates, but rather other non aggregate columns.  On most other databases, and even on MySQL in strict mode, this syntax is not allowed.  Also, there is no need to have 2 subqueries here.  Rather, just select from the basket table and then assert that matching records do not exist in the other table.